# externally actuate a membrane switch

Tags: switches, relay

Is there a standard or recommended way to externally actuate a membrane switch?

Context: I'm trying to interface a programmable controller board (arduino or cousins) to an existing consumer appliance (electric kettle).

I'm open to any kind of solution (relay, optocoupler, mechanical actuator, replacing the appliance's control board). Slight preference for reliability, low cost, and not completely destroying the existing membrane switch.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to both sides of the switch, then adding a mechanical relay in parallel is the quickest simplest way. It also has the most compatibility with however the controller reads the switch (multiplex, charlieplex, scanning, etc), voltage ranges, lack of needing to combine grounds, galvanic isolation etc.

Answer (score 2):

---

If the membrane switch is a part of a low-voltage control circuit - as it should well be - then an optocoupler with a transistor output will work just fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEA5y1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Be sure to measure the voltage polarity across the membrane switch, and ensure that the collector of the optotransistor goes to the more positive potential than the emitter. If the voltage waveform is bipolar (AC) across the switch, then two optocouplers in parallel are needed. If the AC voltage is higher than about 5Vpp, you'll need series diodes to protect the transistors from reverse breakdown:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjKwzi.png)</sup>

In most microcontrollers, the GPIO pin drivers are current sources and will drive two series IR LEDs without external resistors, but you should check the current and ensure it's not excessive, and add a series resistor if so. If the current is too low without a resistor - less than say 5mA - the optocoupler LEDs should be controlled from separate GPIO outputs, using series resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnQnBg.png)</sup>

Comment: Why do you assume it "should well be" low-voltage? In an electric kettle there is probably no microcontroller, no rectifier, etc.

Comment: @user253751 I'm assuming simpler kettles can be analog, but one with a keypad + membrane switches has a controller?

Comment: @user253751 If that membrane switch breaks, and they invariably do, you probably wouldn't want to be touching live mains... Also, membrane switches are typically 50V rated at maximum, so that's the maximum open-contact voltage I'd expect, unless someone really messed it all up (not unthinkable, given how those things are).

Answer (score 1):

The @Passerby answer is good *if* you can reach the contacts. An electric kettle however is probably sealed or has other issues in 'reachability'.

The easiest and cheapest way to push a membrane switch is probably a solenoid, just choose one with the correct force.